# Having a min heigh for bars when building a D3 stack bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to set a min-height for the bars in the stacked graph chart. I have researched and used before in the past d3.domain and d3.range to determine the output and input for single bar chart graphs. But this time it is not working with the stacked layout bar graphs and I am not sure why.  The code is listed below.

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .65);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

 var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

    x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function (d) {
        return d.x;
    }));

    y.domain([0, d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
                function (d) { return d.y0 + d.y;})
        ])
        .nice();

 layer_enter.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.x);
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {

            return y(d.y + d.y0)

        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {

            return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0)

        })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr('class', 'help-text')
        .attr('title', (d) => {
            return this.app.formatNumber(d.y, true);
        });
```

Any suggestions is welcome thank you.

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle representing this problem?

Comment: I can work on refactoring it to work on jsfiddle.